# How do I search the SD card with standard Android File Explorers?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, search, es-file-explorer

My Android Pie SD card storage looks like this:

```
.
├── Android
|   ├──data
|   |  ├── com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping
|   |  |   └── ...
|   |  ├── com.amazon.venezia
|   |  |   └── ...
|   |  ├── com.android.providers.media
|   |  |   └── ...
|   |  └── ...
|   └── ...
└── LOST.DIR
```

If I navigate to `/Android/data/` on the SD card you can see the first three directories are:

1. `com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping`
2. `com.amazon.venezia`
3. `com.android.providers.media`

If I search for the string `venezia` results are only returned for my internal storage, but nothing for the SD card.

Is there a problem with Android search, or is my search procedure wrong? I've tried on multiple Play store file explorers, all with the same result (inability to search SD card).

---

**Edit -** The following Termux commands provide the following output:

```
$ find /sdcard/ -iname '*venezia*'
/sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia

$ ls /sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezia
cache files
```

Comment: What's returned by `find /sdcard/ -iname '*venezla*'` on Termux?

Comment: @Irfan Latif If I issue that command in Termux there's a silent response. In other words nothing happens after pressing `Enter` and I'm just dropped to a fresh command prompt with blinking cursor.

Comment: And what does `ls /sdcard/Android/data/com.amazon.venezla` show?

Comment: @Irfan Latif I had a typo. `venezla` is actually `venezia`. That said, I had to reword the original question. My searches only look at internal storage, it appears the SD card isn't indexed at all. Is this true, and what do I do to be able to search the SD card from any standard Play store File explorer? Termux output included in above in the question. Thank you.

Comment: So now your question should be something like "Why search results in file explorers don't include results from external SD card?". Please consider re-phrasing. // Android provides no search indexing, file explorer apps search files in their own way. Apps don't have filesystem level access to external SD card but they do can search files using SAF for instance. Again it depends on the app you are using.

Comment: he mentioned he was looking for files on sdcard. but find command is targeting internal storage, so `find /storage` is command for searching all

Comment: @alecxs SD card came into scene after edit: https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/218359/1. And he was unable to find the directory because of typo which he has fixed. Now the question is different.

Comment: android 7 file explorer searches case insensitive in both locations by default
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnuXV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMA5t.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7hb1.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX2j6.png